# proving that differentiable vector function $f$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

**Theorem:**

Let $U\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open and $a\in U$

Let a vector function $f: U\to \Bbb R$ be differentiable at $a$

Then prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$

---

**Proof:**

We need to show that $$\lim_{\alpha\to a}f(\alpha)=f(a) \iff \lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)-f(a)=0 \iff \lim_{h\to 0}\vert\vert f(a+h)-f(a)\vert\vert=0$$

Then, let's show that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h}{\vert\vert h\vert\vert}=0$$

$\vert\vert f(a+h)-f(a)\vert\vert \le\vert\vert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h\vert\vert +\vert\vert Df(a)h\vert\vert =\frac{\vert\vert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h}{\vert\vert h\vert\vert}\cdot \vert\vert h\vert\vert+\vert\vert Df(a)h\vert\vert\to 0.0=0$ as $h \to 0$

So, $$\lim_{h\to 0}Df(a).h=0$$ since $Df(a).h$ is linear and so continuous.

---

Is this proof enough ? Does there any mistake or drawbacks?

Comment: Looks correct to me. The formatting could use some work, but that's probably specific to this website.

Comment: This is in fact a theorem. But its proof is not given. Just a hint is given. I proved this by using the hint. Thus, ı want somebody to check this @AlexBecker ıf there exist any a little notation mistake or else, please tell me. This is important for me. Thank you :)

Comment: While the proof is correct, can you not directly use the fact that $f$ being differentiable at $a$ means that it can be written
$$
    f(\alpha+h)=f(\alpha)+Df(\alpha)(h)+o(||h||)
$$
with $Df(\alpha)$ linear (thus continuous and $Df(\alpha)(0)=0$) ?

Comment: Hmmm.. But my proof fomatting is more acceptable in my class. So I did this. Thanks @zuggg

Comment: @zuggg That notion seems more advanced, to me, than the fact that differentiable => continuous.